# Find or Search for a value and get its cell location

Tags: vba, search, find, return, location

The column to Search is A, The value I want returned is from column B (next to it) but also wants its cell address of the value in column B.

So far I have the below (as far is return value in B column)

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

Dim MatchFormula As Long
Dim IndexFormula As Range

MatchFormula = WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("Today"), Range("A:A"), 0)
Set IndexFormula = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("B:B"), MatchFormula, 0)

IndexFormula.Value = Range("G5").Value
End Sub
```

But it says

```
MatchFormula = WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("Today"), Range("A:A"), 0)
```

Gives this error

```
has Run-time error '1004':

Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed
```

Comment: You should qualify your `Range` objects with a `WorkSheet` object.